# Domain name backorder name dot com or namejet

Tags: dns

I'm waiting a domain name from long time (2003 domain), and now this domain will expire at 25/9 , registered at enom.com 
so i found backorder service at name.com no auction or bidding 49USD 
and namejet . com with auction and bidding start from 69 $
namejet is a part from enom
so my question is 
what is the best guarantee way to pick the domain?
I know that no one interesting in this domain , but it is suitable for my project
thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesnt ask any programming related question. It would probably be better suited to http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not directly about programming or software development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enom expiring domains are most likely going to go to NameJet. It's never a bad idea to place backorders with multiple drop catchers. It improves your chances of getting the expiring domain. Just understand that some services (like GoDaddy) will keep your money even if you don't the domain. They will typically apply it as a credit toward future charges. NameJet does not do this. With them you only pay if you win. :)